# Rings, rings, rings and more rings

Tags: riddle, word

My job is putting things in rings.

My prize is rings.

The number of rings I have symbolizes speed.

When people see me in action they say, "Oh, neat!"

Comment: The last line is so hokey that it must mean something. It doesn't rhyme and "Oh, neat!" is not an utterance I hear very often because I'm not trapped in a sitcom from the 50s. I think there's something special beyond just "People thinking watching me is fun."

Comment: @EngineerToast It *almost* rhymes ... but having seen s1e's answer, I think you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some research on Aggie Kidd's answer and I came up to this answer

> Shaquille O'Neal

My job is putting things in rings

> He was basketball player

My prize is rings

> He's got championship rings

The number of rings I have symbolizes speed

> He's got four rings and four rings is an Audi logo

When people see me in action they say Oh, neat!

> He's lastname is the closest to "Oh, neat!" among players who own four rings. Or, "Oh, neat!" is something like "owned".

Comment: Spot on, nice !

Answer (score 3):

A possible answer, but I'm still a little short. Maybe someone can build off of this.

Edit: Still a little stuck, but hopefully this is the right direction.

> Basketball Player,
> specific NBA player (MJ, Bill Russell)?

My job is putting things in rings.

> Put a ball into the ring (hoop)

My prize is rings.

> Championship Rings

The number of rings I have symbolizes speed. (Not so sure here...)

> Maybe speed to greathood, or the Hall of Fame?
> Number of rings that the player has coincides with some symbol for speed... I'm thinking 6 or 11 currently.

When people see me in action they say Oh, neat!

> Good players are a lot of fun to watch, especially the Harlem Globetrotters.

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: What number of rings symbolizes speed?

Comment: I sense Harry Potter....

Comment: No Harry potter. What number of rings is a symbol of speed?

Comment: I think I've got this narrowed down to two possibilities, but I'm having the hardest time thinking of the symbol of speed...

Comment: It could be a basketball arcade, where rings refer to the amount of 0's in your high-score? or maybe in some basketball arcade, if you manage to score certain points within a time frame then they will ring the bell and gives you extra time?

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream Maybe 2 rings (2 rings on a basketball pitch) go together to form the symbol for infinity, and infinite speed is a *lot* of speed?

Comment: No, but if you see the number of rings in question you will definitely associate them with speed.

Comment: Ring the buzzer for the shot clock?

Comment: @The Emperor of Ice Cream - Am I anywhere close with basketball, or sports in general?

Comment: Basketball is good.

Comment: Did you see my most recent edit?

Comment: Yeahm that number of rings is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> Olympics! Summer and Winter Edition!

Reason:

My job is putting things in rings.

> The logo of the Olympics is made of five ***rings***. The medals you wear when you win an event could be a giant ring and the *things* are the contestants.

My prize is rings.

> Like I said before, the medals are kind of like rings. Just bigger and worn around the neck.

The number of rings I have symbolizes speed.

> [Usain Bolt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usain_Bolt), he world's fastest sprinter in the entire world, runs in 5 different events, holding the world records for two of the events he runs in. And there are 5 rings in the logo of the Olympics as said earlier.

When people see me in action they say Oh, neat!

> When people see that the Olympics has started, people could say that. People just love watching the Olympics and cheering their team (country) on. The beginning of the Olympics is a show where people get to see all the teams in a wonderfully displayed stadium hence " Oh, neat!".

Comment: I guess it might be that, but I don't think the job of the olympic games is putting things in rings. Also thinking of the medals as rings is kind of sketchy. Also the number of lanes is not the number of rings.+1 for the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give it a try... IMHO the word "rings" means every time something different:

My job is putting things in rings.

> I had the hardest time with this... Didn't fully understand so I guess my answer is not gonna be right

My prize is rings.

> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prize+rings

The number of rings I have symbolizes speed.

> Each time a round ends, a bell rings. So a fast K.O. means only some "rings"

When people see me in action they say Oh, neat!

> I didn't understand if that is another hint...

So

> you are a boxer... ?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer given by Aggie Kidd. Is it

> a basketball center?

My job is putting things in rings.

> Basketball hoops are ring shaped.

My prize is rings.

> Championship rings.

The number of rings I have symbolizes speed.

> Center is abbrevated "c" (or half a ring) and is the symbol for the speed of light in vaccum.

When people see me in action they say Oh, neat!

> They sometimes make flashy plays!

Comment: Oh wow, that's nice, although the number of rings I want is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is , which is probably wrong, is:

> A circus.  There are multiple rings to a circus.  The more rings a circus has, the faster it can transition between acts, and show more at once.  People seeing a circus go "oh Neat!"

The only thing I am unsure of is My prize is rings but it could mean

> winning ring toss, or the prize position is the center ring.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

> Nascar driver

My job is putting things in rings

> They are paid to drive cars around tracks, which often are in ring shape

My prize is rings

> Winning drivers are awarded championship rings, as it happens for other american sports.

The number of rings symbolizes speed

> Pretty straightforward. The more wins you have, the faster you are in theory.

When people see me in action they say 'Oh neat'

> I'm not a fan personally but some people really enjoy it.

Comment: They are paid to race around the ring. They don't get the cars inside the track.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a

> **Rocket (or  multistage launch vehicle)?**

My job is putting things in rings.

> Rockets or launch vehicles are normally used to put satellites into orbit, which is definitely a ring.

My prize is rings.

> Not sure. May be referring to the interstage rings or stages. Or may be it's about reaching orbit.

The number of rings I have symbolizes speed.

> The interstage rings are used as the separation between different stages ( each stage consists of contains its own engines and propellant) and it can be used to determine the speed or capacity of the rocket.

When people see me in action they say Oh, neat!

> On watching the launching of rockets, people normally wonder Wow, Great, Oh neat etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is

> NASCAR CAR RACE DRIVER.

My job is putting things in rings.

> RACING CAR AROUND THE TRACK

My prize is rings.

> TROPHY RINGS

The number of rings I have symbolizes speed.

> WINNING RINGS MEANS THE DRIVER WAS THE FASTEST

When people see me in action they say Oh, neat!

> MANY LOVE WATCHING FAST CARS

Answer (score -1):

Is it...

> Sonic the Hedgehog game?

My job is putting things in rings.

> I haven't played it so it might be his job

My prize is rings.

> He collects rings to unlock things?

The number of rings I have symbolizes speed.

> Sonic the hedgehog is superfast

When people see me in action they say Oh, neat!

> Kids love watching him run

Comment: The number of rings sonic has doesnt symbolize speed.